# Is working from home a sustainable model for PhD students and academia as a whole?

Tags: phd, university, academic-life, covid-19

I suppose it has its advantages but I’m really starting to struggle with the lack of social contact that working from home entails.

I’d very much like my university to start considering options for a campus based return when the new academic year starts. Considering that I started my PhD and and worked the better part of an entire year remotely, I feel that I’m more than ready to make a campus return.

I suppose my question it this—for people who’ve also worked remotely, is it sustainable and would a face to face return benefit you?

Comment: Some people love work from home. Some people hate it. Depends on many personal factors. Therefore I'm voting to close as opinion based.